# Objective-C: Why use non-NSMutable objects?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Why should someone ever use the non-NSMutable equivalents of the data structures in Objective-C? When it's a situation when you need a `const` object that should not be modified? Does using non-NSMutable classes improve performance in any way? Any other situations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the logic behind having a mutable and immutable versions of classes like NSArray, NSDictionary etc in Objective C ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566673/what-is-the-logic-behind-having-a-mutable-and-immutable-versions-of-classes-like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main reasons off the top of my head:

- An object returning a property can be certain nobody will alter it if it's immutable. The object can therefore return the original instead of making copies all the time. So it's a memory and performance benefit.
- When writing your own immutable objects, it's very easy to be thread safe. That naturally flows into being able to write multi-threaded functional-style code which is reasonably efficient and error free.

You also tend to see arguments in favour of the inherent preservation of the original value being useful, especially in terms of semantics and design patterns.

Immutable classes don't tend to be much more efficient in and of themselves with one exception — if you take an immutable copy of a mutable array, for example, then it's clear exactly how much storage is needed and exactly that much can be allocated. Because memory allocation costs time, mutable collections tend to keep some spare storage around because they can't predict how they're going to grow.

Answer (score 2):

`const` is not directly related to non-mutable objects; I'm more familiar with the latter, so that's what I'll talk about.

A non-mutable object is like a reservation. Imagine that you work at a busy restaurant that only works on a reservation basis—all guests must make a reservation. When someone calls and makes a reservation for eight people at six, you know that you'll be expecting eight people at 6. Of course, this keeps things predictable. You know to set out one table that can sit eight people (it wouldn't make sense to use more than one table, especially at a busy restaurant). You notify the kitchen and tell them to expect eight orders a few minutes after six (okay, maybe you won't, but you might as well). In this way, everything runs smoothly and there are no delays. When the party of eight arrives promptly at six (because everyone in this world is perfectly punctual), you lead them right over to their seats, they order, and enjoy their meal. No problems whatsoever.

A problem arises if the reservation never specifies the number of people or the time. Imagine someone calls and tells you to expect a group of people for dinner. In this case, you have no information. A group could be a couple on a date, a four-person family, or two dozen people for a corporate function. They might arrive late because they were at a movie, really early because they have a young child, or at different times because it was impossible to coordinate everyone. In this case, you would have to scramble to find seating for everyone and the kitchens might suddenly be swamped with a large number of orders. Or you could have blocked off to many seats and the kitchen might find itself with nothing to do. In either case, where you over-estimate or under-estimate, there are delays and lost potential. Anything could happen.

In this metaphor, the restaurant would be the runtime system, and the reservations are the objects. In the first scenario, you have a non-mutable object, like an `NSArray`. The system knows how much data it'll hold, how many elements there are, and by runtime, what type they are. The system knows that the size won't change, so it can optimize RAM to go around that array, without leaving any precautionary bits. Everything runs smoothly because everything is known.

By contrast, nothing is known with an `NSMutableArray.` The user might add more elements, so the system has to scramble to find more RAM, rather than using those same clock cycles to crunch some operation; the user might replace an element in the middle with a larger one, having to offset all the later elements—which involves copying all tho elements after. In certain cases, it could involve copying all the elements of the array or string or whatever to a new location, a (potentially) expensive operation. This can impart a significant performance overhead, especially when you use a lot of them. In Java for example, concatenating a string involves copying the entire existing string to a new memory location, and leaving the garbage collector to deal with the old string.

Another compelling reason is that you make it a bit harder to change the data. Users (of the class) have to explicitly make a mutable copy, which helps to ensure that they know what they're doing. This advantage is particularly notable with multiple threads—you don't want to pass a mutable object to something that's running on a background thread, because the foreground thread (or any other) could then be modifying the object, as it's being modified by the original thread, leading to very interesting results.